# When performing a looking in a Hash data structure, why is it a fast operation?

Tags: data-structures

When you perform a lookup in a Hashtable, the key is converted into a hash.  Now using that hashed value, does it directly map to a memory location, or are there more steps?

Just trying to understand things a little more under the covers.

And what other key based lookup data structures are there and why are they slower than a hash?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Hash (aka Hash Table)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) implies more than a [Map (or Associative Array)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

In particular, a [Map (or Associative Array)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) is an [Abstract Data Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type):

> ...an associative array (also called a map or a dictionary) is *an abstract data type composed of a collection of (key,value) pairs, such that each possible key appears at most once* in the collection.

While a [Hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is *an implementation* of a Map (although it could also be considered an ADT that includes a "cost"):

> ...a hash table or hash map is a data structure that **uses a hash function to map identifying values, known as keys [...], to their associated values** [...]. Thus, *a hash table implements an associative array [or, map].*

Thus it is an implementation-detail leaking out: a [`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is a [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that uses a [Hash-table algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and thus provides the expected performance characteristics of such an algorithm. The "leaking" of the implementation detail is good in this case because it provides some basic [expected] bound guarantees, such as an [expected] `O(1)` -- or constant time -- `get`.

Hint: a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is important part of a hash-table algorithm and sets a `HashMap` apart from other `Map` implementations such as a [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) (that uses a [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)) or a [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) (that uses a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)).

Another form of a Map is an [Association List](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html) (or "alist", which is common in LISP programming). While association lists are `O(n)` for `get`, they can have much less overhead for small `n`, which brings up another point: [Big-Oh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) *describes limiting behavior* (as `n -> infinity`) and does not address the relative performance for a *particular [smallish] `n`*:

> A description of a function in terms of big O notation usually **only provides an upper bound on the growth rate of the function.**

*Please refer to the links above (including the javadoc) for the basic characteristics and different implementation strategies* -- anything else I say here is already said there (or in other SO answers). If there are specific questions, open a new SO post if warranted :-)

Happy coding.

---

[Here is the source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html) for the `HashMap` implementation that is in OpenJDK 7. Looking at the `put` method shows that it a simple *chaining* as a collision-resolution method and that the underlying "bucket array" will grow by a factor of 2 each resize (which is triggered when the load factor is reached). The load factor and amortized performance expectations -- including those of the hashing function used -- are covered in the class documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Hash tables are not necessarily fast. People consider hash tables a "fast" data structure because the retrieval time *does not depend on the number of entries in the table.* That is, retrieval from a hash table is an "O(1)" (constant time) operation.

Retrieval time from other data structures can vary depending on the number of entries in the map. For example, for a balanced binary tree, the retrieval time scales with the base-2 logarithm of its size; it's "O(log n)".

However, actually computing a hash code for an single object, in practice, often takes many times longer than comparing that type of object to others. So, you could find that for a small map, something like a red-black tree is faster than a hash table. As the maps grow, the hash table retrieval time will stay constant, and the red-black tree time will slowly grow until it is slower than a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

"Key-based" implies a mapping of some sort.  You can implement one in a linked list or array, and it would probably be pretty slow (O(n)) for lookups or deletes.

Hashing takes constant time.  In the more sophisticated implementations it will typically map to a memory address which stores a list of pointers *back* at the key object in addition to the mapped object or value, for collision detection and resolution.

The expensive operations are following the list of the "hashed to this location" objects to figure out which one you are really looking for.  In theory, this could be O(n) for each lookup!  However, if we use a larger space the probability of this occurring is reduced (although a few collisions is almost inevitable per the Birthday Problem) drastically.

If you start getting over a certain threshold of collisions, most implementations will expand the size of the hash table, which also takes another O(n) time.  However, this will on average take place no more often than every 1/n inserts.  So we have amortized constant time.